Physical meaning of negative work
I have a simple question here. I've been learning quite a bit about electrodynamics and solving some problems. However, I'm stumbling on a problem: I always get the correct expression of work but have it reversed for some reason. Could someone explain the physical meaning of negative work? Isn't work, after all, energy? How could it be negative? Please try using metaphor and analogy as that would help.

The net work is equal to the change in kinetic energy. Change can be negative. The individual work done by any conservative force is the change in potential energy. Change can be negative.

What would you say is the physical meaning of positive work?

Work is a measure of energy transfer.  A system can gain energy or lose energy.

If a block is sliding on the ground, friction does negative work on the block.  The block loses kinetic energy.
If I push the same block in the direction it is moving, I do positive work on it.  The block gains energy
While pushing the same block, the block does negative work on me.  I lose the energy that I transferred into the block.

The key thing is identifying what did work on what.
Let's say I have two positive charges at rest that are very far apart. I move them to be close together and returned to rest. To do that, I did positive work on the charges.  I used my energy to push them, and the charges gained energy (that is stored as potential energy in the electric field).  If I let go of the close together charges they repel and fly apart.  If I am very careful I can get back all of the stored potential energy, returning the charges to rest very far apart from each other.  I did negative work on the charges taking their energy away, returning them to their initial no (kinetic or potential) energy state.

Work is a measure of energy transfer.
If you are pushing a block and its speed is increasing, you are doing positive work because you are losing energy and the block is gaining it.
From the point of views of the block it is pushing you but doing negative work because it is gaining energy and you are losing energy.

Negative work is work done by the system on whoever is acting on it, as opposed to work being done by the actor on the system.
For example if I want to push a positive charge from far away towards a positive fixed charge, I will have to do work on the system. But if I move a negative charge towards the positive fixed charge (very slowly), it will do work on me as it pulls me toward the fixed charge.

Think of a spring at its natural length and you are pulling the spring, let's say you have pulled the spring and extended its length by $L$. Now it's obvious that work done by you is $kL^2/2$, where $k$ is spring constant (considering you have pulled this things slowly and no work done by you converted into kinetic energy). Now for once, think what is the work done by spring? I am asking this because throughout your motion. This spring also applied a force which is equal to the force applied by you at any particular instant but the displacement for both events, spring so work down by spring is negative times exactly same as your $-kL^2/2$ according to conservation of energy you did some work and you had some particular amount of energy stored in yourself and you did the work on spring so spring gained your energy. So whenever what is done on system, then work done by that particular system is negative. And in simple words, negative work done means rather than doing work and losing energy system gained energy by another system which did work on the system.
